# If number of points on a manifold is $q^n ( [n+1]_q )$ does it imply a geometric relation to $A^n (P^n)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, finite-fields

Consider an algebraic manifold whose number of points is $q^n ([n+1]_q)$.  Is there a geometric relation to $A^n (P^n)$?  In particular, is there an equivalence in the Grothendieck ring of varieties or could there be a birational equivalence?

If there is no such equivalence in general, might some additional reasonable requirements on a manifold force there to be such an equivalence?

---

**Motivation:** one can see that some examples of identities on the level of enumerating $F_q$ points can be lifted to geometric relations:

[Is there a lift of the q-Vandermonde identity to some geometric (motivic) identity for Grassmannians over $F_q$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299581/is-there-a-lift-of-the-q-vandermonde-identity-to-some-geometric-motivic-identi)

[Can one divide algebraic manifolds ? Make sense: $Gr(2,n)/ Gr(2,n+m) = P^{n-1}/P^{n+m-1} P^{n-2}/P^{n+m-2}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299748/can-one-divide-algebraic-manifolds-make-sense-gr2-n-gr2-nm-pn-1-p?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: For the projective case, it seems that fake projective spaces might provide counterexamples (but I don't know enough about these to say for sure). I have no idea what to expect when $X$ has $q^n$ points.

Comment: If you don't require irreducibility, there are easy counterexamples. For example, if $E \subseteq \mathbb P^2$ is an elliptic curve and $E'$ is isogenous to $E$, then $X = (\mathbb P^2 \setminus E) \amalg E'$ has $q^n + \ldots + 1$ points over $\mathbb F_q$.

Comment: Among nonsingular projective varieties, a fake projective plane or odd-dimensional quadrics have the same point count as projective planes. In the case of a fake projective plane its class in the Grothendieck ring is not L^2 + L + 1 (and in fact not congruent to 1 (mod. L) because it's not stably rational). The class of a quadric is same as [P^n] (using projection from the point).

Comment: Have you looked at the literature on polynomial count varieties?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92657/smooth-variety-with-positive-point-count-polynomial-and-odd-cohomology. Especially in the non-projective case, point count itself does not carry enough information to draw strong conclusions. Do you know something about the Hodge theory of your variety?

Comment: It seems more natural here to refer to "algebraic variety" rather than "manifold" if you want to consider points over finite fields.

Comment: @EvgenyShinder It seems your comment gives an answer (negative). May be you can be you can write it as an answer ? (Providing some details would be great ... )

Comment: @Evgeny Shinder, can you give a reference on this statement: "a fake projective plane or odd-dimensional quadrics have the same point count as projective planes"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Russell Cubic $R:=V(x + x^2 y + z^2 + t^3)\subset \mathbb{A}^4$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^3$ although over $\mathbb{C}$ they are both diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{6}$ (see this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_affine_space) page).

I ran a *Mathematica* program I quickly wrote to compute the number of solutions of $x + x^2 y + z^2 + t^3$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$.  For the first twelve primes $p$ (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37) I got $p^3$.

Based on this evidence I guessed that although $R$ and $\mathbb{A}^3$ are not isomorphic that they had the same counting polynomial.

In the comments below, Vladimir Dotsenko, provides an elementary proof of my guess:

> "Consider the zero set of $x+x^2y+z^2+t^3$. Note that for $x\not=0$ we have the unique value for $y$, so this gives $(p−1)p^2$ points ($p−1$ choice for $x$, $p$ choices for $z$, $p$ choices for $t$). For $x=0$, the polynomial becomes $z^2+t^3$, so there are $p$ choices for $y$ and a choice of a zero $(z,t)$ of that polynomial. However, it clearly has $p$ zeros by the usual parametrization of a singular cubic curve: for $t=0$ there is just $z=0$, and for $t\not=0$, we have $t=−(z/t)^2$ so denoting $z/t=u$, we have $(p−1)$ solutions $(u^3,−u^2)$. "

Comment: I don't think Mathematica is needed. Consider the zero set of $x+x^2y+z^2+t^3$. Note that for $x\ne 0$ we have the unique value for $y$, so this gives $(p-1)p^2$ points ($p-1$ choice for $x$, $p$ choices for $z$, $p$ choices for $t$). For $x=0$, the polynomial becomes $z^2+t^3$, so there are $p$ choices for $y$ and a choice of a zero $(z,t)$ of that polynomial. However, it clealy has $p$ zeros by the usual parametrisation of a singular cubic curve: for $t=0$ there is just $z=0$, and for $t\ne 0$, we have $t=-(z/t)^2$ so denoting $z/t=u$, we have $(p-1)$ solutions $(u^3,-u^2)$.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko do not you know it is birational to A^3 ? Same class in Grothedieck ring of varieties ?

Comment: Vladimir's comment also applies to show that the class of this affine cubic is L^3 in the Grothendieck ring.

Comment: Furthermore, the corresponding singular projective cubic 3-fold $XU^2 + X^2Y + Z^2U+T^3 = 0$ has the class $1 + L + L^2 + L^3 = [P^3]$ as the divisor at infinity is the cone over a cusp $X^2 Y + T^3 = 0$.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko Thanks for the proof!  I will edit my post accordingly.